# Save to file results in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

I got a simple async function where I "**scrape**" site from URLs.
Everything works fine, but now I want to save results into my txt file.

I tried to do simply array where I able to push every result also errors;

Now I got a problem where should I do write to file.

I tried putting it to a separated function then do await function inside my async function but function with write to file i always fired first.

There is full code

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const path = require("path");


let urls = [];
let results = [];

(async function readUrls() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("urls.txt");

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (let line of rl) {
    urls.push(line);
  }
  for await (let url of urls) {
    https
      .get(url, (res) => {
        const {
          statusCode
        } = res;
        const contentType = res.headers["content-type"];

        let error;
        if (statusCode !== 200) {
          error = new Error("Request Failed.\n" + `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
        }
        if (error) {
          const firstPath = url.split("/")[7];
          //there is array
          results.push(firstPath);
          //--------------
          console.error("data : " + firstPath + " - " + " nothing found");
          res.resume();
          return;
        }
        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let rawData = "";
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
          rawData += chunk;
        });
        (async () => {
          await res.on("end", () => {
            try {
              const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
              const parsedResult = parsedData["data"]["id"] + " - " + parsedData["data"]["price"];
              //there is array
              results.push(parsedResult);
              //--------------
              console.log("data : " + parsedData["data"]["id"] + " - " + parsedData["data"]["price"]);
            } catch (e) {
              console.error(e.message);
            }
          });
        })();
      })
      .on("error", (e) => {
        console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
      });
  }
})();
```

There is my simple function to write into file

```
fs.writeFile('result.txt', results, +(new Date()), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error occurred", err);
    }
    console.log("File write successfull");
});
```

I tried do something

```
async function secondFunction(){
  await firstFunction();
  // wait for firstFunction...
};
```

What I want to achive? I want to scrape every url from my text file and get ID and Price
( this is simple JSON response into browser no html  - it works )
At the end I want to save everything into text file.

Comment: functions taking callbacks are not `Promise`-returning functions.  You need to wrap them or use `promisify`.  You can't `await` them this way.

Comment: So better is to rewrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a version of your code that uses node-fetch to call the urls. I prefer this one as it is similar to what one can use on the web

To use it you should install it:
`npm install node-fetch`

```js
    const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // I prefer to use node-fetch for my calls
    const fs = require("fs");
    const readline = require("readline");
    const path = require("path");


    let urls = [];
    let results = [];

    (async function readUrls() {
      const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("urls.txt");

      const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity,
      });

      for await (let line of rl) {
        urls.push(line);
      }
      // Make the calls one after the other
      for (let url of urls) {
        try {
          // We can call the urls with node-fetch and await the response
          const res = await fetch(url);
          const { status } = res;
          let error;
          if (status !== 200)
            error = new Error("Request Failed.\n" + `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
          if (error) {
            const firstPath = url.split('/')[7];
            results.push(firstPath);
            console.error("data : " + firstPath + " - " + " nothing found");
            // As we are inside a loop here, we use continue instead of return
            continue;
          }
          try {
            // Here we try to take the response as json
            const parsedData = await res.json();
            const parsedResult = parsedData["data"]["id"] + " - " + parsedData["data"]["price"];
            //there is array
            results.push(parsedResult);
            //--------------
            console.log(`Data: ${parsedResult}`);
          } catch (e) {
            // In case we can't get the response as json we log the error
            console.error(e.message);
          }
        } catch (httpError) {
          //This is for when the call to fetch fails for some reason
          console.error(httpError.message);
        }  
      }
      // Here we join the results to a string so that we can save it properly to the file
      const resultAsText = results.join("\n");
      // Then after all the urls are processed we can write them to a file
      fs.writeFile('result.txt', resultAsText, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error occurred", err);
        } else {
          console.log("File write successfull");
        }
      });
    })();
```

Comment: Perfect, now I just write some limitter to avoid API rate limit